# Test method which invokes another method with runAsync() block

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-test, completable-future

I would be grateful for any advice or practices which you follow.

We use Mockito and Junit4/5 to to write unit tests. However, I see that some tests fail at prod
(when at the end of a test you verify calling of methods which have runAsync block).

Are there exists any options to fix these tests except adding timeout to verify or excluding runAsync() blocks?
TQ in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is your sample code reproducing the problem in a full, but minimal way? Your readers need both application and test code. Stack Overflow is a Q/A platform for concrete programming questions based on code, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your use case looks like exactly, but it sounds like the mission of Awaitility. Have you checked there?

[Awaility-usage-examples](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage#usage-examples)
And nonono, please don't exclude runAsync() blocks. They are testable :)